# Extraction of ids and options from select using BeautifulSoup and arranging them in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, select-options

I have the following html code which I have extracted:

```html
<select class="class1", id="id1">
    <option value="0">A1</option>
    <option value="1">A2</option>
    <option value="2">A3</option>
    <option value="3">A4</option>
    <option value="4">A5</option>
    <option value="5">A6</option>
</select>
.
.
.
<select class="class2", id="id2">
    <option value="0">B1</option>
    <option value="1">B2</option>
    <option value="2">B3</option>
</select>
.
.
<select class="class3", id="id3">
    <option value="0">C1</option>
    <option value="1">C2</option>
    <option value="2">C3</option>
    <option value="2">C4</option>
</select>
```

I need to extract the options and the corresponding ids of each select and arrange them into a Pandas dataframe, similar to this:

| id | option |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | A1 |
| id1 | A2 |
| id1 | A3 |
| id2 | B1 |
| id2 | B2 |
| id2 | B3 |
| id3 | C1 |
| id3 | C2 |
| id3 | C3 |
| id3 | C4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) for this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
parser = BeautifulSoup(s)

d = {'id': [],'option': []}
for s in parser.find_all('select'):
    for o in s.find_all('option'):
        d['id'].append(s['id'])
        d['option'].append(o.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     id option
0   id1     A1
1   id1     A2
2   id1     A3
3   id1     A4
4   id1     A5
5   id1     A6
6   id2     B1
7   id2     B2
8   id2     B3
9   id3     C1
10  id3     C2
11  id3     C3
12  id3     C4
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks @user17242583!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad it helped! (Please accept the answer, then, @Tipo33, as soon as you're able :)